# Can casting be used to change the names of properties?

Tags: c#

Just curious.

I have two objects (in my WCF service):

1. An Entity object, t, and
2. A POCO, ViewEncountertimes.

All the property types are identical between class ViewEncountertimes and entity t, but the property names are different.

This transform works correctly to rename the properties from t to proper PascalCase which I'm using in my data transfer object ViewEncounterTimes:

```
var e = new ViewEncountertimes
                {
                    Age = t.age,
                    Birthdate = t.birthdate,
                    Cashonly = t.cashonly,
                    ChartNumber = t.chart_number,
                    ChartRecid = t.chart_recid,
                    Checkin = t.checkin,
                    Notseen = t.notseen,
                    Checkout = t.checkout,
                    Complexity = t.complexity,
                    Cpatient = t.cpatient,
                    Donotsee = t.donotsee,
                    EncounterRecid = t.encounter_recid,
                    Firstname = t.firstname,
                    Lastname = t.lastname,
                    Mi = t.mi,
                    Newold = t.newold,
                    PatientRecid = t.patient_recid,
                    Recid = t.recid,
                    ServiceRecid = t.service_recid,
                    Sex = t.sex,
                    Ssn = t.ssn,
                    Tcheckout = t.tcheckout,
                    Tencounter = t.tencounter,
                    Visitsprior3years = t.visitsprior3years
                };
```

Is there any way of using casting such that I could say:

> Cast t as ViewEncountertimes

and have the correct names and object type?

(Currently, I am using a separate Transform procedure to make the conversions).

TIA

Edit#1:  Here is the definition of ViewEncountertimes

```
 public partial class ViewEncountertimes
    {
        public int EncounterRecid { get; set; }
        public int PatientRecid { get; set; }
        public int ServiceRecid { get; set; }
        public int ChartRecid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ChartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Cpatient { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tencounter { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tcheckout { get; set; }
        public string Checkin { get; set; }
        public string Checkout { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Notseen { get; set; }
        public string Newold { get; set; }
        public string Complexity { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Mi { get; set; }
        public string Birthdate { get; set; }
        public string Ssn { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Donotsee { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Cashonly { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> Visitsprior3years { get; set; }
        public int Recid { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your object? I'll show you a great way for doing that.

Comment: Look up overriding the explicit cast operator.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Yes...Please see above edit. Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: @AlanWayne I posted a sample model I have, if you need more clarification, let me know and I'll do it with your model.

Comment: By the way, you can change `Nullable<int>` to `int?`

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Sure...no problem. There the same?

Comment: @AlanWayne Yeah, the `?` also make it nullable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting does not change an object - it just changes how properties and method calls are bound by the compiler.  You will have to map by copying the data - either manually as you are doing, dynamically using reflection, or with a third party library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by "dynamically using reflection" ? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne getting a list of properties of the source and destination objects via reflection (`GetProperties`), lining them up, and setting the value of the destination property using the value of the source object's property.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of an object I have created to do just that for me. In this example, both the entity object and my model have an ID, Label, ULabel(uppercase label), MimeType, and a DefaultExtension.

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class ProjectMimeType : ProjectEntity
    {
        public mime_types EntityMimeType = new mime_types(); // Entity Object

        // begin direct db map

        public long Id
        {
            get { return EntityMimeType.mime_type_id; }
            set { EntityMimeType.mime_type_id = value; }
        }

        public string Label
        {
            get { return EntityMimeType.label; }
            set
            {
                EntityMimeType.label = value;
                EntityMimeType.ulabel = value.ToUpper();
            }
        }

        public string Ulabel => EntityMimeType.ulabel;

        public string MimeType
        {
            get { return EntityMimeType.mime_type; }
            set { EntityMimeType.mime_type = value; }
        }

        public string DefaultExtension
        {
            get { return EntityMimeType.default_extension; }
            set { EntityMimeType.default_extension = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

So this way, when I create the object I use, I declare it like the following.

```
    var e = db.mime_types.Find(id);
    var c = new ProjectMimeType{ EntityMimeType = e };
```

Comment: So essentially you're using the constructor to rename the properties?

Comment: All of the properties of the object point to the entity object so essentially just giving them all new names. Make sense?

Comment: The other part of this problem is that the class names also need to be changed to PascalCase. Does this change this approach back to where I started?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, my example is all in PascalCase. When you access any part of my sample object, you'd do `c.MimeType` or whatever you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

To help any newbie like myself, using the previous answers, I created a T4 template for my entity framework to manually map and create my data transfer objects. The below template produces code like this:

```
     public partial class ViewEncountertimes
        {

            public view_encountertimes m = new view_encountertimes();

            public int EncounterRecid { get { return m.encounter_recid; }  set { m.encounter_recid = value; } }
            public int PatientRecid { get { return m.patient_recid; }  set { m.patient_recid = value; } }
            public int ServiceRecid { get { return m.service_recid; }  set { m.service_recid = value; } }
            public int ChartRecid { get { return m.chart_recid; }  set { m.chart_recid = value; } }
            public Nullable<int> ChartNumber { get { return m.chart_number; }  set { m.chart_number = value; } }
            public string Cpatient { get { return m.cpatient; }  set { m.cpatient = value; } }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tencounter { get { return m.tencounter; }  set { m.tencounter = value; } }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tcheckout { get { return m.tcheckout; }  set { m.tcheckout = value; } }
            public string Checkin { get { return m.checkin; }  set { m.checkin = value; } }
            public string Checkout { get { return m.checkout; }  set { m.checkout = value; } }
            public Nullable<bool> Notseen { get { return m.notseen; }  set { m.notseen = value; } }
            public string Newold { get { return m.newold; }  set { m.newold = value; } }
            public string Complexity { get { return m.complexity; }  set { m.complexity = value; } }
            public string Lastname { get { return m.lastname; }  set { m.lastname = value; } }
            public string Firstname { get { return m.firstname; }  set { m.firstname = value; } }
            public string Mi { get { return m.mi; }  set { m.mi = value; } }
            public string Birthdate { get { return m.birthdate; }  set { m.birthdate = value; } }
            public string Ssn { get { return m.ssn; }  set { m.ssn = value; } }
            public string Sex { get { return m.sex; }  set { m.sex = value; } }
            public string Age { get { return m.age; }  set { m.age = value; } }
            public Nullable<bool> Donotsee { get { return m.donotsee; }  set { m.donotsee = value; } }
            public Nullable<bool> Cashonly { get { return m.cashonly; }  set { m.cashonly = value; } }
            public Nullable<long> Visitsprior3years { get { return m.visitsprior3years; }  set { m.visitsprior3years = value; } }
            public int Recid { get { return m.recid; }  set { m.recid = value; } }
        }

Here is the template I used:

    <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#

const string inputFile = @"MedicalOfficeModel.edmx";
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
var codeStringGenerator = new CodeStringGenerator(code, typeMapper, ef);

if (!typeMapper.VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(typeMapper.GetAllGlobalItems(itemCollection), inputFile))
{
    return string.Empty;
}

WriteHeader(codeStringGenerator, fileManager);

foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
{

<#= Mime(code.Escape(entity)) #>

<#
    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}
fileManager.Process(false);

#>


<#+

public static string Mime(string entity)
{
    return string.Format("    public {0} m = new {0}();", entity);
}

public static string GetPascalCase(string name)
{
    return Regex.Replace(name, @"^\w|_\w",
        (match) => match.Value.Replace("_", "").ToUpper());
}                                       

public void WriteHeader(CodeStringGenerator codeStringGenerator, EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager)
{
    fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: true)#>
<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}

public void BeginNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    var codeNamespace = String.Format("{0}.{1}",code.VsNamespaceSuggestion(), "DTO");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(codeNamespace)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent("    ");
    }
}

public void EndNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(code.VsNamespaceSuggestion()))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}

public const string TemplateId = "CSharp_DbContext_Types_EF6";

public class CodeStringGenerator
{
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly TypeMapper _typeMapper;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public CodeStringGenerator(CodeGenerationTools code, TypeMapper typeMapper, MetadataTools ef)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(typeMapper, "typeMapper");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");

        _code = code;
        _typeMapper = typeMapper;
        _ef = ef;
    }


    public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get {{ return m.{5}; }}  {4}set {{ m.{5} = value; }} }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            GetPascalCase(_code.Escape(edmProperty))   ,
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty)
            );
    }

    public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
    {
        var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
            navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
            _code.Escape(navProp),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
    }

    public string AccessibilityAndVirtual(string accessibility)
    {
        return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
    }

    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            GetPascalCase(_code.Escape(entity)),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }

    public string EnumOpening(SimpleType enumType)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} enum {1} : {2}",
            Accessibility.ForType(enumType),
            _code.Escape(enumType),
            _code.Escape(_typeMapper.UnderlyingClrType(enumType)));
        }

    public void WriteFunctionParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction, Action<string, string, string, string> writeParameter)
    {
        var parameters = FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Where(p => p.NeedsLocalVariable))
        {
            var isNotNull = parameter.IsNullableOfT ? parameter.FunctionParameterName + ".HasValue" : parameter.FunctionParameterName + " != null";
            var notNullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", " + parameter.FunctionParameterName + ")";
            var nullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", typeof(" + TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(parameter.RawClrTypeName) + "))";
            writeParameter(parameter.LocalVariableName, isNotNull, notNullInit, nullInit);
        }
    }

    public string ComposableFunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} IQueryable<{1}> {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray()));
    }

    public string ComposableCreateQuery(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<{0}>(\"[{1}].[{2}]({3})\"{4});",
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            edmFunction.NamespaceName,
            edmFunction.Name,
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.EsqlParameterName).ToArray()),
            _code.StringBefore(", ", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray())));
    }

    public string FunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var paramList = String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray());
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            paramList = _code.StringAfter(paramList, ", ") + "MergeOption mergeOption";
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            returnType == null ? "int" : "ObjectResult<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            paramList);
    }

    public string ExecuteFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var callParams = _code.StringBefore(", ", String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray()));
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            callParams = ", mergeOption" + callParams;
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction{0}(\"{1}\"{2});",
            returnType == null ? "" : "<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            edmFunction.Name,
            callParams);
    }

    public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} virtual DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
            _code.Escape(entitySet));
    }

    public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }
}

public class TypeMapper
{
    private const string ExternalTypeNameAttributeName = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration:ExternalTypeName";

    private readonly System.Collections.IList _errors;
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public TypeMapper(CodeGenerationTools code, MetadataTools ef, System.Collections.IList errors)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");
        ArgumentNotNull(errors, "errors");

        _code = code;
        _ef = ef;
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public static string FixNamespaces(string typeName)
    {
        return typeName.Replace("System.Data.Spatial.", "System.Data.Entity.Spatial.");
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, bool? isNullable, string modelNamespace)
    {
        if (edmType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var collectionType = edmType as CollectionType;
        if (collectionType != null)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ICollection<{0}>", GetTypeName(collectionType.TypeUsage, modelNamespace));
        }

        var typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetadataProperties
                                .Where(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName)
                                .Select(p => (string)p.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
            ?? (modelNamespace != null && edmType.NamespaceName != modelNamespace ?
                _code.CreateFullName(_code.EscapeNamespace(edmType.NamespaceName), _code.Escape(edmType)) :
                _code.Escape(edmType));

        if (edmType is StructuralType)
        {
            return typeName;
        }

        if (edmType is SimpleType)
        {
            var clrType = UnderlyingClrType(edmType);
            if (!IsEnumType(edmType))
            {
                typeName = _code.Escape(clrType);
            }

            typeName = FixNamespaces(typeName);

            return clrType.IsValueType && isNullable == true ?
                String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Nullable<{0}>", typeName) :
                typeName;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("edmType");
    }

    public Type UnderlyingClrType(EdmType edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        var primitiveType = edmType as PrimitiveType;
        if (primitiveType != null)
        {
            return primitiveType.ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        if (IsEnumType(edmType))
        {
            return GetEnumUnderlyingType(edmType).ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        return typeof(object);
    }

    public object GetEnumMemberValue(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var valueProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        return valueProperty == null ? null : valueProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public string GetEnumMemberName(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var nameProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        return nameProperty == null ? null : (string)nameProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetEnumMembers(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var membersProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("Members");
        return membersProperty != null 
            ? (System.Collections.IEnumerable)membersProperty.GetValue(enumType, null)
            : Enumerable.Empty<MetadataItem>();
    }

    public bool EnumIsFlags(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var isFlagsProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("IsFlags");
        return isFlagsProperty != null && (bool)isFlagsProperty.GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public bool IsEnumType(GlobalItem edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        return edmType.GetType().Name == "EnumType";
    }

    public PrimitiveType GetEnumUnderlyingType(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        return (PrimitiveType)enumType.GetType().GetProperty("UnderlyingType").GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public string CreateLiteral(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            return _code.CreateLiteral(value);
        }

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "new TimeSpan({0})", ((TimeSpan)value).Ticks);
    }

    public bool VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(IEnumerable<string> types, string sourceFile)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(types, "types");
        ArgumentNotNull(sourceFile, "sourceFile");

        var hash = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (types.Any(item => !hash.Add(item)))
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(sourceFile, -1, -1, "6023",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_CaseInsensitiveTypeConflict"))));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SimpleType> GetEnumItemsToGenerate(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return GetItemsToGenerate<SimpleType>(itemCollection)
            .Where(e => IsEnumType(e));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToGenerate<T>(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection) where T: EdmType
    {
        return itemCollection
            .OfType<T>()
            .Where(i => !i.MetadataProperties.Any(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllGlobalItems(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return itemCollection
            .Where(i => i is EntityType || i is ComplexType || i is EntityContainer || IsEnumType(i))
            .Select(g => GetGlobalItemName(g));
    }

    public string GetGlobalItemName(GlobalItem item)
    {
        if (item is EdmType)
        {
            return ((EdmType)item).Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((EntityContainer)item).Name;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetCollectionNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
    }

    public FunctionParameter GetReturnParameter(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var returnParamsProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("ReturnParameters");
        return returnParamsProperty == null
            ? edmFunction.ReturnParameter
            : ((IEnumerable<FunctionParameter>)returnParamsProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool IsComposable(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var isComposableProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("IsComposableAttribute");
        return isComposableProperty != null && (bool)isComposableProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<FunctionImportParameter> GetParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        return FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
    }

    public TypeUsage GetReturnType(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        var returnParam = GetReturnParameter(edmFunction);
        return returnParam == null ? null : _ef.GetElementType(returnParam.TypeUsage);
    }

    public bool GenerateMergeOptionFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var returnType = GetReturnType(edmFunction);
        return !includeMergeOption && returnType != null && returnType.EdmType.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType;
    }
}

public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T arg, string name) where T : class
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
#>
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth  Sorry, no offense intended. The other answer specifically answered the concept of the question and was more helpful in explaining exactly what casting does and what it can be used for. While being a very good example of implementation, I did not get a clear picture of casting when looking at this implementation, which in all fairness is a mapping solution rather then a casting solution. I certainly do appreciate your help though. Thanks.